# C Makefile not working

Tags: c, makefile

i'm trying to do this makefile, but i'm getting ** missing separator.  Stop.

```
  CC=gcc

    all:
        $(CC) -o sobusrv sobusrv.c 
        $(CC) -o sobucli sobucli.c 

    clean:
        mkdir ~/.Backup
        mkdir ~/.Backup/.data
        mkdir ~/.Backup/.metadata
        mkdir ~/.Backup/.tmp
```

What can be the problem? thank you

Comment: Please post the complete error message with the full context.

Comment: Make sure tabs are used for commands.

Comment: Use tabs at begin of line.

Answer (score 2):

In most makefile environments, TABS and SPACES are treated differently, but look the same on screen.  Check your indentation carefully, and make sure you don't have spaces where tabs are required.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use tabs at the beginning of each command. Take a look at other, working makefile as an example, where tabs are required. Note: even if there is no visible difference to the human eye, tab and space are treated very different by program.